# summing up only certain values in column based on name in ssrs reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

By default, the SUM - sums up all the column values. But in my case, i am having a report which is grouped by Name. A name can have single offer with multiple start date's. So, a report has to display each entry for all different start date i.e Same name, offer, players only difference is the date. So for ex, when you sum up the players, only one entry per name needs to taken into account. Because, even though it has multiple start date, other entries are same and duplicated.

[image]

[image]

The expected result should be like,

[image]

The offer cost $10 refers to same $10, so it should be added only once. Similarly for players, etc., But i need the display as shown above, each entries should be shown.

How to solve this?

Comment: You can add date in column group it will bifurcate the result try doing this and update.

Comment: @AshutoshArya: By adding date in column group, will have those seperate entries. This will again result it summing up all the vales

Comment: Can you provide some example rows with expected results? Are you using 2008 specifically or 2008R2?

Comment: Should the Players Sum only total 2 for that example or 8?

Comment: I think you need to set up a conditional SUM IF expression, do you have a column that changes when its time to start a new sum? If so you should tweak the data set SQL to include a partition over and place a flag such as '1' when that partition ends, then do a sum where partition = 1 to leave out the rest of the items exempt from summing.

Comment: @SelectDistinct: We are grouping the result set on the reports only, not from the sql query. So the changes you were refereing, need the changes in sql query. Instead, is there a way to add one more result set which returns the required sum up result in sql query and bind the same to second row (sum row) in report? Is it possible? If so, how v can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is avoid aggregating the value in the group total row, as in your example, just remove the aggregation from the expression, i.e. change:

```
=Sum(Fields!Players.Value)
```

to:

```
=Fields!Players.Value
```

This just returns the first `Players` value in the Scope - since it's the same value for every row this should be fine.

If you need to further aggregate this value to something like a grand total row, you have a couple of options.

For 2008R2 and above, you can use nested aggregates as an expression in the report - something like:

```
=Sum(Max(Fields!Players.Value,"MyGroup"))
```

For 2008 and below, you will need to add the aggregate value to each row in the Dataset and use this without aggregation in the report as required.

Comment: Did this help with your issue at all?

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t worked with SSRS much but if this was a regular SQL query you would have to group by date range.

Try adding start date column and check if you can add another group by on top of what you already have.

It would be useful if you can provide more details here like table schema you use for retrieving the data.